# Can't view or edit my old Careers CV now that Developer Story exists?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

How do I find my old Careers CV now that Developer Story exists?

I see an option to "re-import the data" from it, so the CV seems to exist, but there's no way to actually see the CV; if I go to careers.stackoverflow.com it takes me to a dashboard used by employers, not a CV page.

If there's no way to view or edit the old CV... then it bothers me that there is an old CV "out there" that I can neither delete nor edit.  Over time it's obviously going to diverge from the current Developer Story version.

Am I missing something?

(And if the old "Careers" site is gone, then why do I have the option to re-import an outdated version of my CV from there?  It's strange that the last update to my old Careers CV would be so immortalized, rather than just migrated once to Developer Story and purged from all other places).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developer Story is the next version of the CV and completely replaces it. This was announced on various channels such as here on meta, our blog, various media outlets and you will also have received an email explaining how your employer-facing data is affected.

Essentially we imported all your data for you and there is no need for you to do anything to remove any of the CV data. We continue to offer the option of re-importing your data from the CV (at least for the next week or so) so that users who want to do so (perhaps due to playing with the feature during private beta) can get things back to a known state.